# How to disable DNN module caching?

Tags: caching, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to customize DNN Html/Text module in following way: it should be invisible if there are specific parameter values in query string. The problem is if it gets rendered at once, it becomes visible always. I have run the web application in debug mode and found out that control Page_Load method is even not executed (other page methods of this control are not executed too), so rendering cycle don't take place anymore.

I found out that after module has been shown for the first time, DNN generates 2 resource files in Cache/Modules, one of them contains html content that gets rendered every time since that moment.

How can I disable that behavior and get module rendered properly every time the page is loaded?

(I've tried to disable DNN caching in host settings, it didn't work)

Comment: This topic is not actual anymore, problem has been solved!

Comment: do anyone have idea.. how to solve the issue??

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it to 0 in the .dnn manifest, but if you added it to a page BEFORE you changed the manifest you will need to open the settings and also set it to 0 there as well, as the old value would be retained.